# Spring Batch Need to skip invalid xml records

Tags: xml, spring-batch

We have a business requirement to process as much of a file as we can and then move

If there is an error in a file with 100 records in record 98, we want to be able to process up to that point and skip the rest of the file, moving on to the next file.

We are processing the files in a MultiResourcePartitioner.

```
<batch:step id="processXMLstep"> 
<batch:tasklet  transaction-manager="transactionManager">
<batch:chunk reader="myXmlItemReader" processor="myProcessor
   Writer="myDBWriter" commit-interval="100"  skip-limit="10000">
<batch:skippable-exception-classes>
<batch:include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
</batch:skippable-exception-classes> 
</batch:chunk>
<batch:listeners>
<batch:listener ref="myFileNameListener" /> 
</batch:listeners>
</batch:tasklet>
<batch:end on="FAILED"/>
</batch:step>
```

The reader is using StaxEventItemReader.

I have added onProcessError(), onReadError(), onSkipInProcess(), onSkipInRead(), onSkipInWrite(), and onWriteError() methods to the listener.  I can see the code hitting the OnReadError() method (and depending on the XML error, the onSkipInRead() method).

Can I do something in the OnReadError() to force the job to just skip the rest of the file and move along to the next file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here has to do with the exceptions that are thrown from the default doRead() method in StaxEventItemReader.  We had to write a custom version that would check for the specific XML exception and then throw it as a custom exception (using that custom exception in the skippable-excpection-classes).

Here is a sample of the custom doRead():

```
    @Override
protected xmlObject doRead() throws CustomXmlException {
    try {
        return super.doRead();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof DataAccessResourceFailureException) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof XMLStreamException) {
                throw new CustomXmlException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if(e instanceof NonTransientResourceException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the the step in the xml:

```
    <batch:step id="processXMLstep"> 
    <batch:tasklet  transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="myXmlItemReader" processor="myProcessor" 
                 writer="myWriter" commit-interval="100" skip-limit="10000">
            <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                <batch:include class="gov.irs.saas.etl.exception.CustomXmlException" /> 
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes> 
        </batch:chunk>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="myFileNameListener" /> 
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:end on="FAILED"/>
</batch:step>
```

This seems to get around the XML errors that would crash the job before (missing start tag on an element, and truncated file where the last xml end tags were missing).